# Упрощение sql запроса Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема с упрощением sql запроса. Вот мой запрос.

```
SELECT count(*) from  ORACLE.Z_DELIVERY
where batch like '%' || :pipeYear || '-' || :pipeNumber 
  and ORG_ID = :shopID 
  and VBTYP = 'T' 
  and PSTNG_DATE =( select max(PSTNG_DATE) from Z_DELIVERY 
                    where batch like '%' || :pipeYear || '-' || :pipeNumber 
                    and ORG_ID = :shopID 
                    and VBTYP = 'T'
                  )
```

Но проблема в том что like два раза очень долго работает. А так как во внешнем запросе с полем batch уже идёт сравнение лайком. Можно же ведь во внутреннем с помощью join это подменить. Если кто может подсказать как это сделать желательно с примером, буду очень благодарен. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: А просто сгруппировать по PSTNG_DATE, отсортировать по его убыванию и взять первую запись - не?

Comment: Вы бы приложили структуру таблицы, индексы и план запроса. Без них оптимизация запроса выглядит гаданием на кофейной гуще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то типа такого:

```
select *
  from (select zd.*, row_number() over 
                    (partition by org_id, vbtyp order by psting_date desc) rn 
          from z_delivery zd)
 where rn = 1
   and batch like '%' || :pipeYear || '-' || :pipeNumber 
   and ORG_ID = :shopID 
   and VBTYP = 'T'
```

И индекс по полю `PSTNG_DATE` будет очень кстати (если еще нет).

Comment: у Вас тут что-то странное написано. у ТСа считалась сумма строк за дату, у вас явно что-то другое

Comment: Всего-то `*` заменить на `count(*)`.

Comment: Условия отбора лучше перенести во внутренний подзапрос. а то получается нам надо сначала пронумеровать все записи в таблице, а потом выбросить большинство из них потому что like и т.п. не прошел. кроме того если по org_id есть индекс во внутреннем подзапросе он может быть использован, а во внешнем уже нет

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуемся функцией [FIRST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm), предложения KEEP:

```
SELECT count(*) keep(dense_rank first order by PSTNG_DATE desc)
  from ORACLE.Z_DELIVERY
 where batch like '%' || :pipeYear || '-' || :pipeNumber 
   and ORG_ID = :shopID 
   and VBTYP = 'T'
```

Comment: Mike спасибо вариант хороший. Только немножко изменилась идея. Нужно просто без лишних функций запрос с этими условиями отсортировать по дате и выбрать первую запись. И вместо count(*) оставить просто *. Если можно приведите пожалуйста такой пример. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
select cnt 
from (              
  select PSTNG_DATE, count(1) as cnt
  from   ORACLE.Z_DELIVERY t
  where  t.batch like '%' || :pipeYear || '-' || :pipeNumber 
  and    t.ORG_ID = :shopID 
  and    t.VBTYP = 'T'
  group  by PSTNG_DATE
  order  by PSTNG_DATE desc
) t
where rownum < 2
```

Во вложенном подзапросе посчитаем сумму по каждому из дней, и во внешнем выведем самый последний день.

Подчеркну сразу, что этот запрос вовсе не обязательно будет работать быстрее вашего(например если у вас есть партиции по дате мой запрос будет заведомо медленнее).
Для оптимизации запроса надо видеть структуру таблицы, индексы по ней и план запроса.

Comment: lDrakonl Ваш запрос работает быстрей но мне нужно сейчас немного другое. Идея поменялась. Нужно просто без всего лишнего выполнить мой запрос и отсортировать по дате строки. И выбрать первую строку которая и будет с максимальной датой. Вот и всё. Если будет пример буду благодарен. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: @Андрей Разве мой запрос делает не то же самое? И посмотрите внимательно на ответ Mike, он точно вам не подходит?

Comment: lDrakonl я чуть чуть переделал как мне нужно правда почти ваш запрос и вышел просто немного нужно  было по другому. Вот как. `select count(1)
from (              
  select batch
  from   ORACLE.Z_DELIVERY t
  where  t.batch like '%' || :pipeYear || '-' || :pipeNumber 
  and    t.ORG_ID = :shopID 
  and    t.VBTYP = 'T'
  order  by PSTNG_DATE desc
) t
where rownum < 2`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ваш запрос просто выведет вам количество строк по вашему условию, никак не привязанному к датам.